# Finding the correct angle from inverse cosine?

Tags: inverse

For my math homework, I have to find an angle of rotation, $\theta$, by cos $\theta$ = $-\sqrt3/2$. When I plug this into my calculator, I get 5$\pi$/6, but the correct answer is -5$\pi$/6. What is the procedure to find the correct angle.

Comment: They are both correct as $\cos\left(\frac {5\pi}6\right)=\cos\left(-\frac {5\pi}6\right)$. You can arrive at this conclusion either geometrically or using the fact that $\cos$ is an even function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the context to figure out which angle is called for. For both sine and cosine, there will be two angles with the given value.

Comment: But −√3/2 is in the 2nd quadrant, and so is 5pi/6. I'm not following the geometry.

Comment: $-\sqrt{3}/2$ is not in any quadrant, since it doesn't represent an angle. $5\pi/6$ is in the second quadrant, and $-5\pi/6$ is in the third quadrant.